# Find the resistance with a dodgy voltmeter

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

> A resistor $R$ of resistance $1200\Omega$ and an unknown resistor $R_x$ are connected in series with a cell of negligible internal resistance. When a voltmeter with internal resistance $r$ is connected across $R$, it reads $0.6 V$, and when connected across $R_x$, it reads $0.9V$.
>
> (a) What is the resistance of $R_x$?
>
> (b) When the voltmeter is connected in series, it reads $0.8V$. What can you deduce about the cell and voltmeter?

I've managed to do part (a). Placing the voltmeter across $R$, the total resistance is $$R_x+\frac{Rr}{R+r},$$ so if $E$ is the emf of the battery, we can compute $$\frac{E}{0.6}=\frac{R_xR+R_xr+Rr}{Rr}.$$ Likewise, attaching the voltmeter across $R_x$, we get $$\frac{E}{0.9}=\frac{R_xR+R_xr+Rr}{R_xr},$$ so dividing the two gives $R_x=1800\Omega$.

However, I'm unsure how to go about part (b). Above, I have some equations involving $r$, but I need to find the emf somehow. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidZ I think it's pretty clear what _specific concept_ the OP didn't understand in this question, and I think they put some effort.

Comment: try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ Homework questions are ok there as long as they show some effort, as yours did.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano What I see this question asking is "From here, I'm stuck." I don't believe that counts as a specific conceptual question. Do you disagree?

Comment: @DavidZ Yes, I disagree, because the conceptual question is in "I cannot seem to get rid of $r$", and this happens because the OP is making the mistake of thinking that the voltmeter is connected _simultaneously_ to both resistors, and this yields to the wrong equation they have written.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano OK, but do you agree that "From here, I'm stuck" does not count as a specific conceptual question? If not, I think we are at an impasse. But otherwise I'd be on board with having the question edited to clarify that it's asking what you say it's asking, and then reopening it.

Comment: @DavidZ _From here, I'm stuck_ is indeed a statement, not a question, but the OP is stuck because they didn't understand a concept which is needed before that point. The OP might not have clear this point and might not be able to formulate the right question, which is just: _What am I doing wrong?_

Comment: Hi @DavidZ, I've updated the question now.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I'd note that "What am I doing wrong?" is also off topic for this site. And jlammy, after your update I think the question still is not appropriate. Things like "I'm unsure how to go about this" and "Any help would be appreciated" tend to indicate that the question isn't suitable for this site. What specifically is holding you up? If you want to ask about finding the EMF, what progress have you made toward doing so yourself and why aren't you able to continue?

Comment: P.S. I deleted some comments which seemed to be moving along the lines of answering the question. Remember that comments are meant for suggesting improvements, requesting clarification, and occasionally linking to related resources.

Comment: @DavidZ You're really exaggerating: my second comment suggested, in fact, an improvement in the solution _already_ found by the OP. So, would you mind behaving in a more considerate way, as expected by a mod?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Since we're at the point where accusations of behaving inconsiderately are being thrown around, I'm not going to respond further. If you want to follow up, feel free to take the issue to [meta] or [chat].

Comment: I think this "and" could be changed to an "or".

Comment: I suggest to try to extend your question with a clearly visible conceptional part, initiate a discussion about it on the meta, and refer to this meta post on the beginning of your question. Remain polite over all limits on the meta. If you do this, I will give you a reopen vote.